# Issue: fragment doesn't get updated when navigate back from sub-activity?

Tags: android

I have 3 tabs in action bar, each tab is associated with a fragment. Each fragment has a ListView which is bind to a SimpleCursorAdapter. When the ListView item is clicked, it navigates to a detail activity, and there is a back button to go back. I expect the ListView get updated when I remove item in the detail activity.

The problem is (Assume the 3 tabs is A, B, C):

1) If I select item from A, and go to the detail page, remove this item, then go back to A, the ListView in tab A get updated, this is what I expect.

2) But if I select tab A, select B, select A again, then repeat the step in 1), the ListView is not updated.

I use the following code to navigate back in the detail activity:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

There is my TabListener:

```
public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        activity_ = activity;
        tag_ = tag;
        class_ = clz;
    }
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {

        if (fragment_ == null) {
            fragment_ = Fragment.instantiate(activity_, class_.getName());
            transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment_, tag_);
        } else {
            transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment_, tag_);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        if (fragment_ != null) {
            transaction.remove(fragment_);
        }
    }
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }

    private Fragment fragment_;
    private final Activity activity_;
    private final String tag_;
    private final Class<T> class_;
}
```

If you need anymore code, just tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it.

Change the TabListener to:

```
public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        activity_ = activity;
        tag_ = tag;
        class_ = clz;
    }
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        if (fragment_ == null) {
            fragment_ = Fragment.instantiate(activity_, class_.getName());
            transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment_, tag_);
        } else {
//            transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment_, tag_);
            transaction.show(fragment_);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        if (fragment_ != null) {
            transaction.hide(fragment_);
        }
    }
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        if (fragment_ != null) {
            transaction.hide(fragment_);
            transaction.show(fragment_);
        }
    }

    private Fragment fragment_;
    private final Activity activity_;
    private final String tag_;
    private final Class<T> class_;
}
```

And in Fragment class's onResume event, re-select the tab.

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(getActivity().getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }
```